# Appv V5.1 - some files are not sequencing correctly

Tags: vcl, bde, appv

I am trying to sequence an application in V5.1 that currently works fine in v4.6.  I have tried to do the conversion and also do a brand new sequence but on both occasions, when the sequenced app is run it errors with "The program can't start because Vcl50.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem".

This file is installed to 'C:\Windows\System32' when I install the client along with a load of other .bpl files. These files are related to the BDE Administrator that it installs.

If I open the bubble for amendment the application works fine and I can see all the .bpl files in the 'C:\Windows\System32' folder.

Comment: Are you installing on a 64bit system?  `vcl50.bpl` is a 32bit DLL, so installing it to `C:\Windows\System32` would be wrong on a 64bit system, you would need to install to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` instead.  A better place to put it is in the same folder as the app that uses it, don't install in a Windows system folder at all

Comment: I am installing/sequencing it onto a 32-bit operating system with Appv-5.  When I install/sequence it on the same operating system(32-bit) in APP-V4.6 it works on 32-bit & 64-bit machines when published.